# Make a +-= Interpreter

Tags: code-golf, interpreter

[+-=](https://esolangs.org/wiki/%2B-#.2B-.3D) is a language created by [Esolangs](https://esolangs.org/) user Anonymous in 2017.
The language consists of only three commands:

- `+` increases the accumulator by one.
- `-` decreases the accumulator by one.
- `=` outputs the accumulator and a newline.

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), all usual golfing rules apply.
- Standard rules apply.
- You may assume input will be valid.
- Interpreters must get input once and output the result.

### Test cases

```
+++++=
5

+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

+++==
3
3

+-=
0

=
0

-=
-1

---=++-=
-3
-2
```

Comment: Can the function take an argument for the initial accumulator?

Comment: @Logern No, it cannot.

Comment: @BgilMidol Not exactly. While it may be deadfish with one less instruction, there are different characters, not just letters.

Comment: I'm in agreement with Bgil Midol that this is a dupe. While it's not exactly identical, the core of the challenge is going to be pretty close to identical.

Comment: There seems to be agreement about this being a dupe, so hammer-voted it

Comment: The lack of a square command and the -1/256 reset make this dramatically simpler to the point that step-by-step execution isn't necessarily the go-to, but I won't personally start a reopen vote since I'm not especially sure that renders it *interesting*.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＩＥ⌕Ａθ=⁻ι⁺κ⊗№…θι-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtJCoAwDAC/UnqK2LxAepCKN8Ev1CoYDK1bBV8fFecyl5kw@z0kzyL9TvEE548TOr9CS3GsmWEzSltdGNVRzAeQUT2/XoxqUh54GsGl/I134MnNaf0OenuNuvipRBDRliVawYsf) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    θ               Input string
  ⌕Ａ                Find all indices of
     =              Literal string `=`
 Ｅ                  Map over indices
       ι            Current index
      ⁻             Subtract
         κ          Number of previous `=`
        ⁺           Plus
           №…θι-    Number of previous `-`
          ⊗         Doubled
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

The number any given `=` prints is equal to the number of `+`s so far minus the number of `-`s so far. The number of `+`s so far plus the number of `-`s so far plus the number of `=`s so far is of course the index of the `=` in question, so the number of `+`s plus `-`s can be calculated from the difference, and the difference between the number of `+`s and `-`s by further subtracting double the number of `-`s.

As @Jonah points out in his J answer, you can also translate the `-=+` characters to the integers `-1..1`, and output the cumulative sums at the positions of the `0`s. This also takes 16 bytes in Charcoal:

```
ＩＥ⌕Ａθ=ΣＥ…θ⊕ι⌕=+λ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtRCoQgFACvIn490XeCxY9FCPoIgk4gKiS8rMyCTv92a35nJsy@htUT81hzaeD80WDwG3S5xC8R7EZIK5UR07m8wt2BkpvX7VF9CTUtqbQUIat/9WwgrZZGkHr5MCOi1Rot40U/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    θ               Input string
  ⌕Ａ                Find all indices of
     =              Literal string `=`
 Ｅ                  Map over indices
         θ          Input string
        …           Truncated to length
           ι        Current index
          ⊕         Incremented
       Ｅ            Map over characters
               λ    Current character
            ⌕       Find index in
             =+     Literal string `=+`
      Σ             Take the sum
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Charcoal's `Find` returns `-1` when there is no match, which is what we want for `-`.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>29 26</sup> 25 bytes

```
0(=echo"++/\@])'-='&i.-1:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DTRsU5Mz8pW0tfVjHGI11XVt1dUy9XQNrf5rcnGlKahrg4CtOhdIkbo6WMQWE6LIA9VDBRSgIrooClA4qFK6urq22iDl/wE)

*-3 thanks to ovs!*

*-1 thanks to Neil!*

Inspired by [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245681/15469).

Consider `+=+=`:

- `'-='&i.-1:` Convert `-=+` to `_1 0 1`

  ```
  1 0 1 0
  ```
- `0(=...+/\@])` Scan sum  and filter only elements at the `0` positions:

  ```
  1 0 1 0  ...  1 1 2 2
  1 2                  NB. 1 and 2 are the values at the 0 positions
  ```
- `echo"+` Print each value

  ```
  1
  2
  ```

Comment: The `@#` is not necessary, dyadic `echo` does exactly what you want. Using 0 as a left argument for the inner function saves another byte: [26](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DTRsU5Mz8pW0tfVjHGI11XVttdXVMvV0Da3@a3JxpSmoa4OArToXSJW6OljEFhOiyAPVQwUUoCK6KApQOKhSurpAB4CU/wcA)

Comment: Thanks very much for reminding me of this.  I had totally forgotten about dyadic echo.

Comment: I think you can use `'-='` because the fallback result for `:` is the length of the string, so this ends up mapping `+` to `2` anyway.

Comment: @Neil Nice observation, thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to update your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 73 bytes

```c
f(char*p){int a=0;p--;while(*++p)*p==43?a++:*p==45?a--:printf("%d\n",a);}
```

Ungolfed:

```c
void f(char*p){
    int a=0; // Accumulator
    p--; // The loop increases the pointer so compensate
    while(*++p){
        if(*p==43)a++; // 43 and 45 are ASCII codes for + and -
        else if(*p==45)a--;
        else printf("%d\n",a);
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9RC8IgEMef26cQIdBdR0H1MpM@SPUgttVBOZlR0NhnX@rqKQ/0f6fn/3cWL9aOYyPs1XSllz25BzN6pTyiel3pVosSwMvSa71Z7w1AleV2bxAr38XnjeDz89HxhZFqGFP/3ZATz5bOsi9s68KD5d@ZNaEOhxPTrOeQluYLxkH/R67H@0lgPvI2SUTUkMqDKpq2E8mUIjTtAr3rNk6TnOTylyV3qQggAs1@0Ec3Dwl7oqKTVMXs2zllQzGMHw)

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY/NDoMgDMfP4ykIiYmIZEu2XWTEB5keGtSNw4CI2WHEZ3eg87Q2Kf1I@f@q@EOpZQEx5OoJY@FoGOyYgzyJwgnHGC0cv5zrFK@1G7WZhpxkXWNICbQCzitgTMxLHOAXaJO/re5oQMoaP@H1T6zA9/7eYokDYckkKTFh8t/XfpxvCV@fNWwp51yy1J4FSphJVEdUffP609t4Q1Kix71K6lToeEVAhx2@MZlP@BuVbqlAh9/mVs1oXr4 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 44 bytes

```
=
=¶$`=
-1=A`
%O`.
+`\+-

((-)+|\+*)=+
$2$.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w35bL9tA2lQRbLl1DW8cELlX/BD0u7YQYbV0uLg0NXU3tmhhtLU1bbS4VIxU9w///tUHAlotL2xYTAkWBciBKF0gAEYjS1dW11QYKAAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
=
=¶$`=
```

Prepend all of the prefixes of the input that end in an `=`.

```
-1=A`
```

Delete the original input. (Assuming it ended in an `=`, this will have been prepended as the last prefix.)

```
%O`.
```

Sort the characters in each prefix.

```
+`\+-
```

Cancel out the `+`s with the `-`s.

```
((-)+|\+*)=+
$2$.1
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Î„+-„><‡.V
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cN@jhnnaukDCzuZRw0K9sP//dXV1bbW1dW0B) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TpuSZV1BaYqWgZF@pw6XkX1oC4en8N6h81DBPWxdI2Nk8alioF/b/0Db7/9ogYMulbYsJuUAyQFLXlsuWC0jo6uraagN5AA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Î           # Push 0 and the input
 „+-        # Push string "+-"
    „><     # Push string "><"
       ‡    # Transliterate all "+" to ">" and "-" to "<" in the input
        .V  # Evaluate and execute as 05AB1E code:
            #  `>`: Increase the top by 1
            #  `<`: Decrease the top by 1
            #  `=`: Print the top with trailing newline, without popping
```

Because `=` in 05AB1E does exactly what we want it to in +-=, it might be the perfect language for this challenge.